# Bootstrap form inline and automatic datepicker date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to build a quick reservation using bootstrap form inline. but I have some problem:

1. Form inline has a margin left [**I not want any margin left**]
2. Datepicker can not automatic to generate check out date [**after click check in date ex: 22/10/2013 system automatic go to check out date 23/10/2013 so user can't hard to begin from this date**]

How to do that?
This my script html

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls form-inline" id="sandbox-container">
                    <label for="check-in">CHECK - IN</label>
                    <input type="text" id="cid" name="fymd" class="span2 input-append date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
                    <label for="check-out">CHECK - OUT</label>
                    <input type="text" id="cod" name="tymd" class="span2 input-append date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

bootstrap javascript for datepicker I use from [here](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) .
This javascript inline

```
<script>
$('#sandbox-container .input-append.date').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startDate: "0d",
    endDate: "+2y",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
</script>
```

File CSS is standard from bootstrap.
This is the screenshot: [image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Issue 1:** The correct structure for an inline form is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <form class="form-inline" id="sandbox-container">
            <label for="check-in">CHECK - IN</label>
            <input type="text" id="cid" name="fymd" class="span2 input-append date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" />
            <label for="check-out">CHECK - OUT</label>
            <input type="text" id="cod" name="tymd" class="span2 input-append date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FV5pR/2/embedded/result/)**

**Issue 2:** The [plugin page](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) you linked to has a full example with the functionality you want

Comment: why demo fiddle can not be opened?

Comment: @LenaQueen what do you mean? the demo is only for the new markup so you see there's no margin now, I didn't include the datepicker plugin